# T-SQL Find Comma Seperated Values IN Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, list

Part Table

ID   Name    Compatible Models ID's (CS Values)
--   --------   -------------------------
1    Z-Rot   1,2,3 
2    Rot        1,2,4
3    Rotil    1,2,7

Model Table

ID     Model
--     -------
10    3.16
9      5.20
7      3.18
1      7.35
2      8.50
3     X5
4     X6

I need this result 

ID     PART NAME   Models               Models (ID)
--     ----------------   -------------     --------------
1      Z-ROT              7.35,8.50,X5     1,2,3
2      ROT                 7.35,8.50,X6     1,2,4
3      ROTIL              7.35,8.50,3.18   1,2,7

How can i do that?

Comment: Somehow separated values can easily be splitted in general purpose programming languages (C++, C#, Java, VB ...); however, you will have a hard time doing it in SQL!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: With Jeff Moden's Tall-Ho CSV splitter readily available as a *Best Practice* your comment is no longer true. See my answer below and here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/splitting-a-csv-column-from-select-query-into-multiple-columns/72298#72298

Comment: It does not look like an easy to understand piece of code.

Comment: i need to select and join list in list so what i can do with this -> CsvValues.split(',');

Comment: The code isn't easy to understand at a first glance. But a relational database isn't designed for storing and handling comma separated lists either... Therefore, I recommended the normalized form of how the data should be stored. You simply can't expect simple code if you don't follow simple rules.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: The bulk of the code is in-line creation of a CTE tally table (which most SQL developers will already have statically defined) and comments. How about actually trying to read the code before condemning it as *too complex*.

Comment: Anyway your current tables design is wrong. We should just use  ***atomic*** values in relational database (`1,2,3` here is not atomic, because it consists three sub-values). Otherwise you may encounter a very complex query (and also unreliable) such as in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is preferred to keep your database tables in at least 0th normal form (with no repeating groups), in the case that you re stuck with the existing schema you can use [Jeff Moden's Tally-Ho CSV splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) to parse your CSV fields:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
WITH E1(N) AS (
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
       ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
            SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() 
                                                        OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
        ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just
                     -- once for each delimiter)
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
        ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
            SELECT s.N1,
                   ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
            FROM cteStart s
        )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final
     -- element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
go
```

[A usage example is in this dba.stackexchange post of mine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/splitting-a-csv-column-from-select-query-into-multiple-columns/72298#72298)

Comment: M.Ali solution is ok. This one is more complex than other. Thx Pieter.

Comment: @TCCinoMarzano: If you have a large data volume, (say more than a thousand or two rows), measure performance before making that decision final. The XML solution looks elegant and simple, but may be non-performant on large data volumes.

Comment: Thanks Pieter, i'll take care about your advise.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to change the table design to have a single row per compatible model, preferrably a separate table:
CompatibleModelsPerPart Table

ID  PartId  CompatibleModelsId

---

1   1      1

2   1      2

3   1      3

4   2      1

5   2      2

6   2      4

...

The values in the Models column would then have to be splitted. After that you could perform an inner join and if the data match you could pivot the result set (usually at the application layer).

Comment: of course you right but current issue is about comma seperated values.

Comment: ... As is my answer. Once you overcome the de-normalized way to store the data (a "list" in a column), the query itself becomes straight forward. It'll be faster, easier to understand and easier to maintain...

Comment: one part and several brands & models in a field can be fast as you describe but not can  handle in web applications easily.

Comment: With a robust design the web application would call a stored procedure for any data manipulation and at the minimum a view (or, again, a stored procedure) for a select. The SQL code would take care to provide the data in the best way the app can handle without violating any basic database rules.

Comment: Your right but you have think something different sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a split function for this...

### Split Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split]  
    (  
      @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),  
      @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)  
    )   
 RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))  
AS  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @xml XML  
  SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'  

  INSERT INTO @t(val)  
  SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item  
  FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)  
  RETURN  
END
```

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @Part TABLE(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20), CompatibleModels VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Part VALUES 
(1,'Z-Rot','1,2,3'),
(2,'Rot'  ,'1,2,4'),
(3,'Rotil','1,2,7')


DECLARE @Model TABLE(ID INT, Model VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Model VALUES 
(10 ,'3.16'),(9  ,'5.20'),(7  ,'3.18'),(1  ,'7.35')
,(2  ,'8.50'),(3  ,'X5'),(4  ,'X6')
```

### Query

```
 ;WITH CTE AS
 (
  SELECT *
  FROM @Part t
       CROSS APPLY(SELECT Val FROM dbo.split(t.CompatibleModels,','))C(Model_Ids)
),
CTE2 AS
 (
    SELECT C.ID
          ,C.Name AS PartName
          ,C.CompatibleModels
          ,M.Model
          ,Model_Ids
    FROM CTE C INNER JOIN @Model M
    ON C.Model_Ids = M.ID
 ) 
SELECT ID
      ,PartName
      ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' +  Model
              FROM CTE2
              WHERE  C2.ID = ID
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
              .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS Model
     ,C2.CompatibleModels
FROM CTE2 c2
GROUP BY C2.ID, C2.PartName, C2.CompatibleModels
```

### Result

```
╔════╦══════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ PartName ║      Model       ║ Model_Ids ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════╣
║  2 ║ Rot      ║ 7.35, 8.50, X6   ║ 1, 2, 4   ║
║  3 ║ Rotil    ║ 3.18, 7.35, 8.50 ║ 1, 2, 7   ║
║  1 ║ Z-Rot    ║ 7.35, 8.50, X5   ║ 1, 2, 3   ║
╚════╩══════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: Great solution.
Thx. M.ALi

Comment: Not a problem @TCCinoMarzano, glad to help :)

Comment: Some advisors say this code is heavy.
I have checked on 14K records. 
(Top 30 Distinct record from 14K Part Tables)
It took 0.326 Sec on 8 GB Ram Quad Core Xeon SQL Server 2012.

Comment: for 14K records with this kind of schema I would say its not a bad time. you should look into fixing the actual problem. That is your schema, you should get your data atleast in 3rd normal form. and performance of your database will improve and you will end up writing much simpler queries.